How to split pandas Series into two based on whether or not the index contains a certain word?
I have pandas series that I want to split into two: one with all the entries of the original series where index contains a certain word and the other with all the remaining entries.
Getting a series of entries which do contain a certain word in their index is easy:
foo_series = original_series.filter(like = "foo")

But how do I get the rest?

You could drop those indices from the original Series:
foo_series = original_series.filter(like = "foo")
non_foo_series = original_series.drop(foo_series.index)

Or use boolean indexing:
m = original_series.index.str.contains('foo')
foo_series = original_series[m]
non_foo_series = original_series[~m]

Example:
# input
original_series = pd.Series([1, 2, 3, 4], index=['foo1', 'bar1', 'foo2', 'bar2'])

# outputs
# foo_series
foo1    1
foo2    3
dtype: int64

# non_foo_series
bar1    2
bar2    4
dtype: int64


You could pass a regex to pandas.Series.filter().
foo_series, nonfoo_series = (
    original_series.filter(like="foo"),
    original_series.filter(regex=r"^(?!.*foo)")
)

This regex can be visualised as:

Output (sample data from the answer by Mozway):
foo_series
foo1    1
foo2    3
dtype: int64

nonfoo_series
bar1    2
bar2    4
dtype: int64

